# Auto update a field in a list based on another

Tags: list, list-form

I am making a contract management list. I need the value of column (status) to show active if end date not reached. expired if reached or exceed today, and to show upcoming if end date and today is less than 60

Comment: Do you want to create calculated column (cannot edit manually using form) for this or just populate the status on list form & users can change manually?

Comment: to note the solution should be able to ready system date. and not return the value based on when the data in the list was created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have at least two ways to do what you want:

1. As suggested, create a Calculated column. You can use an existing column of the list and create a formula to display what you want: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)
2. Another solution consists to format your view. This solution has the pro that you do not have to add a field into your list: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Hoping this will help you